# Display Posts Category Wise

Tags: wordpress

I have code to show the latest 3 posts of every category and I want to exclude the child categories, but it doesn't exclude the sub category and it shows sub category separately and it show the latest 3 posts of sub category. Is there any way to exclude sub categories from loop.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
//start page loop
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    //get meta to set parent category
    $library_filter_parent = '';
    $library_parent = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wts_library_parent', true);
    if($library_parent != 'select_library_parent') { $library_filter_parent = $library_parent; } else { $library_filter_parent = NULL; }
    ?>

    <div id="library-by-category-wrap">

        <?php
        //get meta to set parent category
        $library_filter_parent = '';
        $library_parent = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wts_library_parent', true);
        if($library_parent != 'select_library_parent') { $library_filter_parent = $library_parent; } else { $library_filter_parent = NULL; };

        //term loop
        $terms = get_terms('library_cats','orderby=custom_sort&hide_empty=1&child_of='.$library_filter_parent.'');
        foreach($terms as $term) { ?>

            <div class="heading">
                <h2><?php echo $term->name; ?></h2>
            </div>

            <div class="library-category">

                <?php
                //tax query
                $tax_query = array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'library_cats',
                        'terms' => $term->slug,
                        'field' => 'slug'
                    )
                );
                $term_post_args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'library',
                    'numberposts' => '3',
                    'tax_query' => $tax_query
                );
                $term_posts = get_posts($term_post_args);

                //start loop
                foreach ($term_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);

                    //get images
                    $featured_image = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'cat-thumbnail'); ?>
                      <?php if(!empty($featured_image)) { ?>
                          <div class="library-item">
                            <a class="library-title" href="#" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" target="_blank">
                                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                            </a>
                          </div>
                          <!-- /library-item -->
                      <?php } ?>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
            <!-- /library-category -->

        <?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    </div>
    <!-- /library-by-category-wrap -->

    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
//get all terms (e.g. categories or post tags), then display all posts in each term
$taxonomy = 'category';//  e.g. post_tag, category
$param_type = 'category__in'; //  e.g. tag__in, category__in
$term_args=array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC'
);
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy,$term_args);
if ($terms) {
  foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    $args=array(
      "$param_type" => array($term->term_id),
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'caller_get_posts'=> 1
      );
    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
      echo 'List of Posts in '.$taxonomy .' '.$term->name;
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
       <?php
      endwhile;
    }
  }
}
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>
```

Note see the Time Parameters in the query_posts() article.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php // get all the categories from the database
$cats = get_categories();
// loop through the categries
foreach ($cats as $cat) {
// setup the cateogory ID
$cat_id= $cat->term_id;
// Make a header for the cateogry
echo "<h2>".$cat->name."</h2>";
// create a custom wordpress query
query_posts(“cat=$cat_id&post_per_page=100");
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php // create our link now that the post is setup ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php echo '<hr/>'; ?>

<?php endwhile; endif;
// done our wordpress loop. Will start again for each category ?>

<?php } // done the foreach statement ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $catquery = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'testimonials', 'category_name'=>'hello','posts_per_page' => 10 ) );
    while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
?>
<ul>
    <li>
        <h3>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h3>
    </li>
    <li>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </li>
</ul>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$taxonomy = 'category';
$term_args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'parent' => 0
);
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy, $term_args);
```

Comment: Hi @Navnit, code only answers are usually frowned upon here. And for a good reason (see Pierre's comment). Your answer should always contain some description of what your code accomplishes and why and what should OP tinker with. Please edit your answer accordingly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
[homepage_cat_grid limit='3' cat_id='2']

add_shortcode( 'homepage_cat_grid', array($this, 'homepage_postgrid_shortcode') );

/**
 *  HOME PAGE CATEGORY WISE POST GRID
 */
public function homepage_postgrid_shortcode( $atts, $content ) {
    
    extract( shortcode_atts( array (
        'order'    => '',
        'orderby'  => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'cat_id'=> ''
    ), $atts ) );
    ob_start();
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'order'     => $order,
        'orderby'   => $orderby,
        'posts_per_page' => $limit,
        'cat'         => $cat_id
    );
    $home_post = new WP_Query( $args );
    
    if( $home_post->have_posts() ) : ?> 
    
    <div class="post-header">
        <div class="head-left">
            <?Php 
                $terms = wp_get_post_terms($home_post->post->ID,'category'); 
                $cat_nm=$terms[0]->name; 
                if($cat_nm=='News'): echo "Recent News"; else: echo $cat_nm; endif;  
            ?>
        </div>  
        <a href="<?php
        $category_link = get_category_link( $terms[0]->term_id );
        echo $category_link; ?>" class="btn post-head-btn">VIEW ALL</a>
    </div>  
    
    <div class="row">
        <?php while ( $home_post->have_posts() ) : $home_post->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="single-grid">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ); ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="post-caption">
                        <?php echo the_category(); ?>
                        <div class="post-heading">
                            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post-content">
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <a class="btn btn-dark cust-btn" href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>">Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </div>  
    
    <?php else :
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
        endif; 
        return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: That is a substantial block of code you have provided without much context. Maybe it does offer the answer to the question but could you at least include some explanation for what this code does and how it works? Even some comments in the code would be helpful. Thanks for your contribution.