# Wordpress list all categories and posts

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, categories

My code is mostly working but there's a small problem.

I am expecting to see this output...

**Cats**

- Domestic
- Ragdol

**Dogs**

- Pug
- Bloodhound

But instead I am getting:

**Cats**

- Domestic
- Ragdol
- Pug
- Bloodhound

**Dogs**

- Domestic
- Ragdol
- Pug
- Bloodhound

As you can see every post is being listed in each category, instead of just the posts for each (sorry - unintentional pun) respective category.

Here's is my code:

```
<?php
$cat_args = array(
'taxonomy' => 'animal_category'
);

$categories = get_categories($cat_args);

foreach ( $categories as $category ) { 
$category_hero = get_field('hero', $taxonomy . '_' . $category->term_id); ?>

<div class="gallery">

    <div class="gallery-hero">
        <h2><?php echo $category->name; ?></h2>
        <img src="<?php echo $category_hero["sizes"]["Full"]; ?>" />
    </div>


    <?php
    $cat_ID = $category->id;
    $post_args = array(
            'showposts'         => -1,
            'post_type'         => 'gallery',
            'offset'            => 0,
            'category'          => $cat_ID
        );
    $posts = get_posts($post_args);

    foreach($posts as $post) {  ?>
        <div class="gallery-box">
            <?php $gallery_image = get_field( "photos"); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $gallery_image[0]["sizes"]["Medium"]; ?>" />
                <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>


</div>
```

Everything looks right to me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502227/display-posts-category-wise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error on your code. Use with the following code. I Hope this will work correctly.

```
<?php
$cat_args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'animal_category'
);

$categories = get_categories($cat_args);
foreach ( $categories as $category ) { 
$category_hero = get_field('hero', $taxonomy . '_' . $category->term_id); ?>
<div class="gallery">

    <div class="gallery-hero">
        <h2><?php echo $category->name; ?></h2>
        <img src="<?php echo $category_hero["sizes"]["Full"]; ?>" />
    </div>


    <?php
    $cat_ID = $category->term_id;
    $post_args = array(
            'showposts'         => -1,
            'post_type'         => 'gallery',
            'offset'            => 0,
            //'category'          => $cat_ID
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'animal_category',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $cat_ID
                )
            )
        );
    $posts = get_posts($post_args);

    foreach($posts as $post) {  ?>
        <div class="gallery-box">
            <?php $gallery_image = get_field( "photos"); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $gallery_image[0]["sizes"]["Medium"]; ?>" />
                <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```